# Why can't windows create dithered colors for all pen styles?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc, gdi+, gdi

Refer to the following lines from "Programming Windows With MFC (2nd ed.)" by Jeff Prosise.

> Only `PS_INSIDEFRAME` pens greater than 1 logical unit in width can use dithered colors. For the other pen styles, Windows maps the color of the pen to the nearest solid color that can be displayed.

If windows is capable of creating dithered colors, then why doesn't it do so for all other pens as well?

Comment: Because there wasn't enough demand for that feature in the other styles to justify the extra work to implement them?

Comment: But if it could be done for one, how difficult would it be to add support for others. Your point about there not being enough demand needs some more elaboration. PS_INSIDEFRAME, is just one of the many styles a pen can have, why give it special preference over others ?

Comment: You probably don't want dithering if your pen style is dotted or dashed.  That leaves solid pens.  If your pen is 1 logical unit wide, you probably don't want dithering then, either.  If your pen is many logical units wide, you may as well use a brush.  Remember, dithering is from a time when spatial and color resolutions were extremely low.  Dithering for things like lines looks terrible.  I suspect there was one particular use case for which somebody did the work to make PS_INSIDEFRAME work.

Comment: Thanks, your comment was quite insightful.